# Did Yorick ever use flash paper in 'Y: The Last Man'?

Tags: comics, vertigo-comics, y-the-last-man

I can see that he bought flash paper, when he found Beth's ring, as pictured below:

[image: Panel from Comic]

But did we ever see him use it in the series?